Closedness of a subgroup of SU(3)
Consider
\begin{equation}\sigma_1 = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}, \quad \sigma_2 = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix},
    \quad 
    \sigma_3 = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -i \\
        0 & i & 0
    \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
They share some important algebraic properties of Pauli matrices:
\begin{equation}
    [\sigma_j,\sigma_k] =  i \sum_{\ell=1}^3\varepsilon_{jk\ell}\sigma_{\ell}, \qquad \mathrm{Tr}(\sigma_j\sigma_k\sigma_{\ell} )=i \varepsilon_{jk\ell}, \qquad \forall j,k,\ell\in\{1,2,3\},
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon_{jk\ell}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol. And
\begin{equation*}
    e^{i\theta \sigma_1} = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos \theta & i\sin \theta & 0 \\
        i\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} \in SU(3)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    e^{i\theta \sigma_2} = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos \theta & 0 & i\sin \theta  \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        i\sin \theta & 0 & \cos \theta 
    \end{pmatrix}\in SU(3)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    e^{i\theta \sigma_3} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
        0 & -\sin \theta & \cos \theta
    \end{pmatrix}\in SO(3).
\end{equation*}
In fact, $\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\}$ is a subset of the Gell-Mann matrices $\{\lambda_j:j=1,\cdots,8\}$ ($\sigma_1 = \lambda_1$, $\sigma_2 = \lambda_4$, $\sigma_3 = \lambda_7$),  the latter forms a  basis of generators of the Lie group $\mathrm{SU}(3)$. From the algebraic properties of $\sigma_k$ we get that
$$\mathfrak{h}: = \{c_1 i \sigma_1+c_2i \sigma_2 +c_3 i \sigma_3: c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
is a Lie sub-algebra, by Lie group-Lie algebra correspondence, there exists a Lie sub-group $H$ of $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ such that the Lie algebra of $H$ is $\mathfrak{h}$. In fact,
$$H = \{e^{X_1}\cdots e^{X_n}:X_1,\cdots,X_n \in \mathfrak{h}\}.$$
My question: Is $H$ closed in the sense of topology? I know that not every Lie sub-group of SU(3) is closed, for example, the irrational line on the torus.
Any help will be appreciated.

Yes, $H$ is just a copy of $SU(2)$ in $SU(3)$.

@Qiaochu Yuan Could you kindly give me an idea about your claim?

$\mathfrak{h}$ is a copy of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, so $H$ can only be either $SU(2)$ or $SO(3)$, and it turns out to be a copy of $SU(2)$.
